# How to extract GeoJSON database column as geometry layer? (column as layer)

Tags: leaflet, javascript, html

Have a one table of country with multiple categories for states. Table as below:

Country table:(converted shapefile to GeoJSON for use in Leaflet choropleth map)

[image]

So kind of table converted from shapefile to GeoJSON using QGIS for further procedure.

How can I convert these categorical columns into categorical layers for choropleth mapping?

Comment: This question is in no way connected with Leaflet.

Comment: Here I am just mention that where I want to use it. So mention Leaflet(For reference).